# How to populate a ComboBox from a DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, dataset

I'm trying to populate a combobox from a dataset with only specific rows, this is my code:

```
comboBox2.DataSource = glObalDataSet.Tables["JOBURI"].Select(
               "CONT = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'");
```

The dataset works fine, it is populated, can someone show me where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Elaborate on your question.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or Silverlight?

Comment: it dosen't show any error, and dosen't populate my combobox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DataView to filter the result.

```
DataView dv=glObalDataSet.Tables["JOBURI"].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter="CONT = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
comboBox2.DataSource=dv;
comboBox2.DisplayMember="JOB";
comboBox2.ValueMember="ID";
```

You need to set `Display` and `Value` member property of [Combobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) control.

Comment: I tried to do like this, but it doesen't work:comboBox2.DisplayMember = dv.Table.Columns[1].ToString();

Comment: There are  3 Colums {"CONT","JOB","id" }

Comment: Did you set DisplayMember="JOB" (no need to set ValueMember if you bind single field)? Also double check the combbox1.SelectedValue.

Comment: I used comboBox2.DisplayMember = "JOB";
                MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); and stil no result :|

Comment: I used the StepOut tool (F11) to see what information is in my dataview, and I saw that it finds th table "JOBURI" in the dataset but whene it gets to the RowFilter, to filter to rows by the Colum "CONT", it dosen't have items. it's empty.